# problems with each()

Tags: jquery, each

I am trying to insert a link at the end of each `.item`.

Everything is working fine but I get 7 printouts of the link after each element. 

How can I get just the relevant link to print after each of it's `.item`?

Thank you so much!

```
$('#content .item img').each(function(i) {
    var altText = $(this).attr("alt");
    $('<br /><a href="' + altText + '">visit website</a>').insertAfter('.imagefield');
});
```

Comment: more code pls. Preferably a sample of your html

Answer (score 2):

Change your selector to only find `#content .item`, not the images within. Presumably you're iterating over any nested images within `.item` (which would appear to be 7)

Remember that each will find all matches for the selector. If you're intent is only to work with `.item`, then you need to be specific and only select `.item` (not nested elements).

With no HTML in front of me, I would recommend:

```
$('#content .item').each(function(i,e){
  $(e).append('<br /><a href="' + $('img',e).attr('alt')+ '">visit website</a>');
});
```

Comment: Also, if need be you can nest another `.each()` to work with all images within the `.item` match. But, again, I don't have any HTML and am only making assumptions at this point.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `insertAfter('.imagefield')` which will find all .imagefield elements and insert a link after them - for each image. Try `insertAfter(this)`.